# I can't work out the entropy formula for TraMineR

Tags: r, entropy, traminer

I used the `ggseqplot()` library to calculate the entropy from the `TraMineR` library. To familiarise myself with the formula, I tried unsuccessfully to calculate it by hand using simple example data.

Alphabet : 3

Probability of each event: 1/26, 22/26, 3/26

The calculation obtained by `ggseqdplot(mine_mvad.seq, with.entropy = TRUE)` gives me 0.265087328, which is the default normalised entropy.

The formula [here](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf) is pp.77-78.
I tried :
`- 1/log(3) / ((1/26*(log(1/26)) + 22/26*log(22/26) + 3/26*log(3/26)))`

and

`- (1/26*log(1/26) + 22/26*log(22/26) + 3/26*log(3/26))`
But I don't have the right result. I've missed something in the formula.

Comment: I have the basic formula, with the calculation of the natural logarithm, but I don't understand the expression "entropy is normalised, ie divided by the entropy of the alphabet" in the default mathematical formula, which is supposed to give the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shannon's entropy of a distribution $(p_1,...,p_n)$ is $-\sum_i p_i \log(p_i)$. In `TraMineR`, the entropy is computed with the natural logarithm.

`TraMineR` computes both the longitudinal entropy (i.e., the entropy of the distribution within each sequence) with function `seqient` and the cross-sectional entropy of the state distribution at each position with function `seqstatd`. Function `ggseqdplot` (from package `ggseqplot`) plots the cross-sectional distributions and the cross-sectional entropies. The plotted values are taken from the outcome of `seqstatd`.

In your example, we do not know to what the distribution `c(1/26, 22/26, 3/26)` corresponds. If it is the distribution inside a sequence of length 26 you should compare with the outcome of `seqient`. If it is the distribution, say at the first position, across 26 sequences, then you should compare with the outcome of `seqstatd` (the entropy is the third element of the returned list or `$Entropy`). Both return normalized values. The normalization is done by dividing by the maximal possible entropy for the given alphabet, which is the log of the alphabet size. In both cases, you can get non-normalized values by specifying `norm=FALSE`.

To illustrate, I build a set of 26 sequences of length 26 using alphabet `{"a","b","c"}`.

```
library(TraMineR)
sdat <- c("a/1-b/22-c/3","b/2-c/24","c/5-b/10-a/11")
sda <- sdat[c(1,rep(2,22),rep(3,3))]
sdsts <- seqformat(sda, from="SPS", to="STS", 
              SPS.in = list(xfix = "", sdsep = "/"), stsep="-")
myseq <- seqdef(sdsts, cnames=1:26)
seqIplot(myseq)
```

[image: dplot of myseq]

Now, we compute the cross-sectional entropies and display the first five values:

```
myseq.distr <- seqstatd(myseq)
myseq.distr$Entropy[1:5]
##         1         2         3         4         5 
## 0.4695343 0.3255263 0.1483905 0.1483905 0.1483905
```

The first value (i.e., the cross-sectional entropy at the first position) is obtained as:

```
ent <- -((1/26*(log(1/26)) + 22/26*log(22/26) + 3/26*log(3/26)))
ent/log(3)
## [1] 0.4695343
```

The cross-sectional distributions and entropies are plotted with

```
seqdHplot(myseq)
```

[image]

We get the longitudinal entropy of the first sequence with

```
seqient(myseq[1,])
##       Entropy
## [1] 0.4695343
```

and non-normalized value with

```
seqient(myseq[1,], norm=FALSE)
##       Entropy
## [1] 0.5158361
```

The value of the normalized entropy is the same as the entropy computed transversally at the first position because, by construction of our example data, the distribution within the first sequence is the same as the cross-sectional distribution at the first position.